# Out Sequence -- Enrich mediator is not working as expected

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I trying to build a application which includes service chaining. When i try to merge the responses and do the extra transformation on the merged response.. i see unintended response.I see the response i merged along with my xslt transformation outcome

For example:

If i have added "abc" to my existing outcome using enrich -> sibling to body option, after i do transformation, i still see "abc" getting appended.

Please see my code below

```
<enrich>
                        <source clone="false" type="custom" xpath="get-property('poecResp')"/>
                        <target action="sibling" type="body"/>
                    </enrich>
                    <log category="INFO" level="full" separator=","/>
                    <xslt key="conf:Response_V1.xslt"/>
                    <log category="INFO" level="full" separator=","/>
```

in the last log i print i see the sibling i added still remains.

Comment: I did not get your question. May be you can send the soap messages before and after xslt.

Comment: i want to send it after the xslt. But the message is not getting formatted correctly as per xslt. I mean when i do a transformation on the soap body it was not taking the output of xslt as the soap body. Perhaps its attaching some more extra tags which i used earlier. My XSLT is working as expect. i see not issues with transformation file.

Comment: check without the enrich mediator what happens with the xslt. I am not sure how exactly sibling of soap body works eg (target action="sibling" type="body"). this may add another child element at the soap body.

Comment: yes it is adding another child... but after that im trying to use enrich component to replace the soap body with teh content i need. But it does not seems to be working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see the issue is with xslt. i should choose the "Source XPATH". But not sure still why my Enrich component is not working.